# When medial ‹d› represent /dʒ/?

Tags: pronunciation

When does medial ‹d› represent /dʒ/ e.g. educate, graduate, soldier, ... ? Is there any rule?

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the Longman Pronunciation Dictionary, p. 206:

> Less frequently, the pronunciation [of d] is dʒ as in **gradual**,
>   **procedure**. This pronunciation comes about through yod coalescence [see [here]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_consonant_clusters), and applies where the spelling is **du**, most
>   typically where **u** counts as a weak vowel. Some BrE speakers also
>   do this where u counts as a strong vowel, and likewise where the
>   spelling is **eu**, **ew** as in **dew**, **due** dju: or dʒu:.

Comment: This is consistent with what I found in the *Oxford Companion to the English Language*.